# How to retrieve the related model when using create() in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Is there a way to chain the method with and create together?
I have tried to to do something like this and it doesn't work..

```
return Post::with('User')->create($inputs);
```

if I use:

```
return Post::create($inputs)->user();
```

I'll only get the user not the post.

The last option is:

```
$post = Post::create($inputs);
return Post::with('User')->find($post->id);
```

There must be a better way to do it, I guess.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? The `with()` method is for eager loading.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve a json where the post has its user associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you will do it like in your example

```
Post::with('User')->create($inputs);
```

how do Laravel will know to what exact user attach this new post?

That's why you have do it like this:

```
// Get your user
$user = Auth::user();

// Create new post
$post = new Post($inputs);

// Attach your post to a user and save it
$user->posts()->save($post);
```

Comment: if I do return $post; after the code above, I'm not getting the user.

Comment: @MakSuriyaJacobsen You can return $user

Comment: I need to use the post which has the user not the other way around, because after I've created the post, angularjs will receive the post json and add it to the posts array.

Comment: @MakSuriyaJacobsen Ok, after it will be saved use `return $post->load('user');` and it will be returned with the associated user's data.